# Повелительное наклонение

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие постоянные и непостоянные признаки повелительного наклонения глагола?

Comment: Информация на эту тему: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/32442534

Answer (score 2):

У глагола:

**Постоянные признаки**:
а)   вид;
б)   переходность;
в)   спряжение.

**Непостоянные признаки:**
а)   наклонение;
б)   время (у глаголов изъявительного наклонения);
в)   число;
г)    **лицо** (в настоящем и будущем времени, **в повелительном наклонении**);
д)   род (в прошедшем времени и в условном наклонении у глаголов единственного числа).

**Пример разбора**:

***Выходи*** — глагол, так как обозначает действие предмета.

Н.ф.: выходить

П.п.: несовершенный вид, непереходный, невозвратный, II спряжение.

Н.п.: употреблён в форме **повелительного наклонения**, 2 лица, единственного числа.

Повелительное наклонение выражает побуждение к действию,  а не само действие, поэтому в повелительном наклонении глаголы **не имеют категории времени.** Время относится только **к реальному действию** и обозначает отношение действия к моменту речи.

Глаголы в повелительном наклонении изменяются **по числам и лицам**.

Чаще всего употребляются  формы **2 лица** единственного и множественного числа, которые выражают побуждение к действию собеседника (собеседников).

Форма **1 лица** повелительного наклонения выражает побуждение к совместному действию, участником которого является и сам говорящий: давай играть, давай споём.

Формы **3 лица** единственного и множественного числа повелительного наклонения являются аналитическими (состоят из нескольких слов): пусть уходит, да здравствует.

https://blog.tutoronline.ru/kategorija-naklonenija-glagola

Answer (score 0):

***Постоянные:* вид** (совершенный/несовершенный), **спряжение** (первое/второе)

***Непостоянные:* число** (единственное/множественное), **лицо** (первое/второе)(без третьего).

***Вид:***

> Совершенный: **Сбеги** от них так быстро, как только можешь.
>
> Несовершенный: **Пишите** грамотно.

***Спряжение:***

> *Первое спряжение:* **Помоги** ему (помогать).
>
> *Второе спряжение:* **Сходи** в магазин (сходить).

***Число:***

> *Единственное:* **Уходи**, и больше не возвращайся!
>
> *Множественное:* **Уходите**, и больше не возвращайтесь!

***Лицо:***

> *Первое:* **Пошли**, нам тут делать нечего.
>
> *Второе:* **Уходите**, и больше не возвращайтесь!

Comment: Глаголы повелительного наклонения не имеют категории времени. И разве "умоляю" - это повелительное?

Comment: И еще:  "пить", "выпивать" - глаголы первого спряжения.

Comment: "Пощади" — несовершенный вид?